# Codeigniter does not recognize newly-added controller

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I had been using CI very well for some time. Today I added a new contoller called "gallery" but it didn't work. It showed an error "404 (Page Not Found) Error". And this is the link if you want to have a look http://picask.net/gallery. It seems that it can not automatically route to the default index function in the controller any more. But it is very strange that other controllers which were added in the past and written in the same format all still work well(This is the most important point of this question!) For example: http://picask.net/about this link works.

I guess it may be because of the htaccess file. But I'm not sure because I didn't change the file when adding the new controller "gallery". Anyway here is the content of my htaccess file if it may be the reason:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
#RewriteBase /picask/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 

#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And this is the controller file gallery.php (Note: I've seen on the internet some people had the same problem because they copy from an exsiting controller but forget to change the file name, but this is not my case):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gallery extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
          // I commented everything just to make it easier to figure out the problem
          // 

    }
}
?>
```

And the 'about' controller is in the same format but works:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class About extends CI_Controller
{   
    function index()
    {
        //deleted content
    }
}
?>
```

And the routs.php file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Could anybody tell me where is wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would need to see the controller file as well as the routes file at a minimum to determine what's going on

Comment: Have you extended to the ci_controller ? can you post your gallery controller ?

Comment: @cdbconcepts I have posted the controller. thanks.

Comment: @Akhil SidharthI have posted the controller. thanks.

Comment: let's see the routes file

Comment: when i hit url `http://picask.net/about` it keep me right page 
but when i hit url `picask.net/gallery` it redirect me `http://picask.net/gallery/` add `/` at last

this mean something wrong in routes file

Comment: is the name of the file gallery.php ?

Comment: @Akhil Sidharth. Yes, the name is gallery.php.

Comment: @Girish where is the routes file?

Comment: application/config/routes.php, can you show us

Comment: @Kai Qing. could you tell me what is the routes file?

Comment: can you also show application/config/routes.php - the routes file

Comment: @cdbconcepts could you tell me what is the routes file? do you mean some setting in the config file?

Comment: @KaiQing I have posted the routes file. :)

Comment: @Girish I have posted the routes file. :)

Comment: @AkhilSidharth I have posted the routes file :)

Comment: What operation system? Your both files names starts with small or upper letters?

Comment: @indapublic both 'gallery' and 'about' starts with lower case letters.

Comment: lol do you have a directory on your server called `gallery` or just a file without an extension?  your rewrite rules don't trigger in this case. -f and -d d00d.

Comment: @Rooster. You are right!! I have a directory on the server called "gallery"! And that's the reason. I've fixed it. Thanks a lot. Also thanks to those who are racking brains to help me.

Comment: @Girish my problem has been solved. it is because of a folder under the root directory with the same name as the controller. I renamed the folder and it works now. But the link shown on the browser still have "/" appended at the end. As you said, it indicates an error. So what is wrong? you can check the link http://picask.net/gallery/

Comment: @Rooster the problem is solved. But I have one more question: the link which shows on the browser has "/" appended at the end. This is different from the 'about' controller. But why? There should not be "/" at the end.

Comment: thats how directories are shown....

Comment: @Rooster but other controllers do not have "/". e.g., the 'about' controller, http://picask.net/about